# Django get context data across Views

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I know that there are several generic views like `ListView`, `DetailView`, or simply `View`.
The thing is can I actually get the context data that are declared in a `BaseMixin`'s `get_context_data()` and use it in a View that doesn't have override `get_context_data()`?
Example:

```
 class BaseMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(BaseMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['test'] = 1
        return context
```

And the view that extends this `BaseMixin`:

```
class FooView(BaseMixin, View):
    def foo(self, request):
        context = super(BaseMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # do something 
       return
```

This is not working actually, even after put `**kwargs` as a parameter in `foo()`. The error is `'super' object has no attribute 'get_context_data'`.
So is there a way to get context data which was set in `BaseMixin` in `FooView` ?

Thanks for your answers :)

Comment: Well, `object` doesn't have a `get_context_data` method... you should probably inherit from a Mixin class

Comment: You must always use the *current* class in any super call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Sayes and all answer posters, I finally solved this problem.
From what I figured out, the problem is actually in `BaseMixin`, the inherited class of `BaseMixin`, which is `object`, doesn't have a `get_context_data()` function, just like @Sayes commented.
After replace this `object` with `ContextMixin`, everything works perfectly, at least perfectly for now.

Here is the modified `BaseMixin`:

```
class BaseMixin(ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do something
        return context
```